# string includes <br/> doesn't show line break in HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add a line break between **Can get report** and **Can order** in a table cell like this:

```
Can get report

Can order
```

This is code in csHTML file:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    @{
       string role = string.Empty;
       if (p.CanGetReport)
       {
         role = "Can get report" + "<br/>";
       }
       if (p.CanOrder)
       {
        role = role + "Can order";
       }
     }
    <td>@string.Format(role)</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Already used string.Format to encode the tag `<br/>` to a break line in output. But it doesn't work as I expected.
this is the output:

```
Can get report <br/>Can order
```

Need help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To output html tags from string you shoul use method [HtmlHelper.Raw](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.web.webpages.html.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-webpages-3.2)

```
@Html.Raw(role)
```

Comment: perfect, completely saves my time. It works now. Thank you a lots.